# How to solve this sum with Riemann-sum?

Tags: calculus

The question is to prove that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty }\left [ \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n.p} \right ]=\ln(p)$$

I want to transform it to Riemann-sum and solve it with integral, I can transform it like this:

$$ \frac{1}{n} .\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}+\frac{1}{n}.\frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{n}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}.\frac{1}{1+(p-1)(\frac{n}{n})} $$

but after that I'm stuck, I can't deal with $(p-1)$ in the denominator.
for example if $p = 2$ then sum becomes

$$ \frac{1}{n} .\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}+\frac{1}{n}.\frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{n}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}.\frac{1}{1+(\frac{n}{n})} $$

that is more simpler to turn to a Riemann-sum and solve it with:

$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x}\,\mathrm{d}x=\ln(2)$$

Answer (score 0):

We can separate each $n$ terms, so the sum turns to sum of $p-1$ sums,
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n.p} \right]
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{kn+1}+\frac{1}{kn+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{kn+n}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left [\frac{1}{kn+1}+\frac{1}{kn+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{kn+n}\right ]\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\int_0^1\dfrac{1}{k+x}dx\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\left(\ln(k+1)-\ln(k)\right)\\
&= \color{blue}{\ln p}
\end{align}